# calling functions from array but each function wants different value

Tags: python, arrays

similar topics have been opened, but I couldn't find exactly what I wanted and couldn't solve it myself.

What I want is to call my functions from an array in a loop, but the values ​​that each function needs are different. Sending all values ​​to all functions (they won't use what they don't need after all) or coding all 20 of my functions with if else is a solution but it seems like there must be a more efficient way.
Is there a solution? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
 def a_func(x1):
      return x1
 
 def b_func(y1):
      return y1

 mylist=['A','B']
 dictionary = {'A': a_func, 'B':b_func}

 def main(x1,y1):
      for each in mylist:
           value=dictionary[each](???) #x1 or x2 how can i send different variable according to each func
```

Actually, all the answers were indirect solutions, but ILS's comment was working in different multi-functions, I needed to be more specific in the question, thank you very much, I understood the logic.

Comment: Do you want to pass `x1` to `a_func` and `x2` to `b_func`?

Comment: yes different values for different functions in a loop

Comment: Do these functions all take only one argument in your scenario?

Comment: No one of them has 7 variable and other just 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments, your actual situation is more complex.

Assuming you have `a_func` taking one argument, `b_func` taking two arguments, and you have three variables `a, b, c` to `main`. You want to pass `a` to `a_func`, and `b, c` to `b_func`. I think you need to group arguments by functions before passing them to `main`, i.e., calling `main((a,), (b, c))`. Then you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#zip) to pass i-th argument group to i-th function.

```py
def a_func(a0):
    return a0
def b_func(a0, a1):
    return (a0, a1)
func_list = [a_func, b_func]
def main(*argv):
    for func, arg in zip(func_list, argv):
        func(*arg)

main((a,), (b, c)) # In main, you call a_func(a) and b_func(b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer:

```py
    def a_func(x1):
        return x1

    def b_func(y1):
        return y1

    funcs = [a_func, b_func]

    def main(inputs):
        x1 = 0
        y1 = 1
        inputs = [x1, y1] # suppose it is given from out of this function
        func_outputs = []
        for i in range(len(funcs)):
            func_output = funcs[i](inputs[i])
            func_outputs.append(func_output)
            print(func_output)
```

as an example:

```py
    inputs = [0, 1]
    main(inputs)
```

**output**

```py
    0
    1
```

Comment: as an example i wrote single variable but i have multivariable functions so passing both lists in order may not be the solution buti guess if i assign variables with 2d list it can work let me try

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse `**kwargs` for this

```py
def a_func(x1, **kwargs):
    return x1


def b_func(y1, **kwargs):
    return y1


mylist = ["A", "B"]
dictionary = {"A": a_func, "B": b_func}


def main(x1, y1):
    for each in mylist:
        value = dictionary[each](x1=x1, y1=y1)
        print(value)

main(1,2)
```

**output**

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation of @EdoAkse's answer. If you cannot modify `a_func`/`b_func`, you can create a dictionary with lambdas:

```py
def a_func(x1):
    return f"{x1=}"


def b_func(y1):
    return f"{y1=}"


mylist = ["A", "B"]
dictionary = {
    "A": lambda **kwargs: a_func(kwargs.get("x1")),
    "B": lambda **kwargs: b_func(kwargs.get("y1")),
}


def main(x1, y1):
    for each in mylist:
        value = dictionary[each](x1=x1, y1=y1)
        print(each, value)


main(10, 20)
```

Prints:

```
A x1=10
B y1=20
```